# implementing string into comparable interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation

Im a newbie coder and I was getting very frustrated because I keep getting compiler errors. This is a homework assignment and what I'm suppose to do is implement the Comparable class to compare any two String objects so it will return the maximum and minimum. I keep getting compiler errors and I dont exactly know why I do.

```
public class DataSet implements Comparable
{
   private Object maximum;
   private Object least;
   private int answer;

public int compareTo(Object other)
{
answer = this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
return answer;

}

public Object getLeast(Object other)
 {
   if(answer<0)
   return this;
   else
   return other;
  }

 public Object getMaximum(Object other)
 {
   if(answer>0)
   return this;
   else
   return other;
 }


}
```

the error is the getName Method

```
public interface Comparable
{
    public int compareTo(Object anObject);
}


public class DataSetTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    String s = "john";
    String a = "bob";
    ds.s.compareTo(a);
    System.out.println("Maximum Word: " + ds.getMaximum());
    System.out.println("Least Word: " + ds.getLeast());

 }
}


incompatible types
    String s = "john";

incompatible types
    String a = "bob";

error: cannot find symbol
    ds.s.compareTo(a);

 error: method getMaximum in class DataSet cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("Maximum Word: " + ds.getMaximum());
error: method getLeast in class DataSet cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("Least Word: " + ds.getLeast());
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the assignment.  Comparable is an interface containing the `compareTo()` method, which returns -1, 0  or +1 if the `this` object is "less than", "equal to" or "greater than" some other object.  It does not find a maximum or minimum.  The way you have described the assignment does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) already implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, so I'm not sure what exactly your task is.

```
answer = this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
```

`Object` has no `getName()` method. If you implemented it in `DataSet` you need to change the type of `other` or add a cast:

```
answer = this.getName().compareTo(((DataSet)other).getName());
```

.

```
incompatible types
    String s = "john";
```

This is strange. Maybe you created your own `String` class? If so, you cannot assign java's `String` to your `String`

```
error: cannot find symbol
    ds.s.compareTo(a);
```

`DataSet` has no field `s`. Expression `ds.s` is not valid.

```
error: method getMaximum in class DataSet cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("Maximum Word: " + ds.getMaximum());
```

You need to add argument to `getMaximum()` e.g. `getMaximum(null)`. Or, remove the argument from method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The methods are declared so they receive an **Object**.

So when you try to use `getMaximum()` (with no parameter) it doesn't find the method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you were asked to implement Comparable or Comparator? Strings already implement Comparable and will produce an int if you call

```
String firstString = "AAA";
int compareToValue = firstString.compareTo("BBB");
```

A Comparator has the signature

```
int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
```